# Excel extract all rows from another dynamic workbook with criteria

Tags: excel, master-detail

I have a excel master list (Master.xls) which is updated regularly with tons of rows of data example it has unique column A,B,C,D,E. I need to create a new workbook (Report.xls) with reference to the master list (without editing or adding filter in master list) and extract all the rows that fulfill criteria example, get and display all the rows that column C = 300. In way where by when i update the master list, this report will update after refresh.

I tried online using Index but is not working and trying to minimise the use of macros or vba

Comment: what have you tried so far? Also, what element are you using? a button or what? please make your question more informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the perfect scenario for Power Query. Use it from a new workbook, load the master workbook into the query editor, filter and clean the data as you need and save to a sheet.

When the data in the master file changes, all you have to do is refresh the query. All this can be done without writing a single line of code, just clicking icons in the user interface.